# Python - text is flipped using camelot to extract table from PDF

Tags: python-camelot

I'm using library camelot to read PDF and extract tables.
For most PDF it works perfectly.
But for other PDF, the text is flipped.

Does anyone know what causes it and how to fix it?

Here's the link to the PDF:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Br34gJlx_7VUBmTYCTKXy1502qls44i7/view?usp=sharing

NOTE: the PDF is in hebrew, which in-a-way should be flipped, but it happens ONLY for this kind of PDF,
Also note that English and number got flipped as well
e.g. `HSITIRB` should be `BRITISH`

```js
[
    [
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "20/21/0202",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "",
            "7": "",
            "8": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "",
            "3": "20/10/1202",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "",
            "7": "",
            "8": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "",
            "7": "20/21/0202",
            "8": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "םוכס",
            "1": "ךיראת",
            "2": "",
            "3": "םוכס",
            "4": "סיטרכ",
            "5": "טוריפ",
            "6": "ףנע",
            "7": "קסעה תיב םש",
            "8": "ךיראת"
        },
        {
            "0": "בויח",
            "1": "בויח",
            "2": "",
            "3": "הקסעה",
            "4": "גצוה",
            "5": "",
            "6": "",
            "7": "",
            "8": "הקסעה"
        },
        {
            "0": "08.269",
            "1": "50/11/02",
            "2": "",
            "3": "26.373",
            "4": "אל",
            "5": "-ב . תירבה תוצרא יוכיז",
            "6": "תוריית",
            "7": "6211390024521   A HSITIRB",
            "8": "13/01/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "2/11/02",
            "6": "",
            "7": "",
            "8": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "3.0004",
            "6": "",
            "7": "",
            "8": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "08.269",
            "1": "",
            "2": "20/11/05",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "",
            "7": "",
            "8": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "",
            "7": "20/21/0202",
            "8": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "םוכס",
            "1": "",
            "2": "םוכס",
            "3": "סיטרכ",
            "4": "",
            "5": "טוריפ",
            "6": "ףנע",
            "7": "קסעה תיב םש",
            "8": "ךיראת"
        },
        {
            "0": "בויח",
            "1": "",
            "2": "הקסעה",
            "3": "גצוה",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "",
            "7": "",
            "8": "הקסעה"
        },
        {
            "0": "00.66",
            "1": "",
            "2": "00.66",
            "3": "אל",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "םיסנניפ",
            "7": "םימולשת תייצקילפא ייפ",
            "8": "50/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "00.10",
            "1": "",
            "2": "00.10",
            "3": "אל",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "דרשמו דויצ",
            "7": "טנרטניא קווש יקצמיטס",
            "8": "90/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "00.50",
            "1": "",
            "2": "00.50",
            "3": "אל",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "םיסנניפ",
            "7": "פ\"הנב TIB ב הרבעה",
            "8": "11/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "00.362",
            "1": "",
            "2": "00.362",
            "3": "אל",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "םיסנניפ",
            "7": "פ\"הנב TIB ב הרבעה",
            "8": "51/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "00.170",
            "1": "",
            "2": "00.170",
            "3": "אל",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "ןוזמ",
            "7": "ובטימב ינגרוא - עבט תרומש",
            "8": "61/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "60.130",
            "1": "",
            "2": "60.130",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "ןוזמ",
            "7": "הרדח ףוננחוי",
            "8": "61/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "48.99",
            "1": "",
            "2": "48.99",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "ןוזמ",
            "7": "הרדח ףוננחוי",
            "8": "61/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "00.99",
            "1": "",
            "2": "00.99",
            "3": "אל",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "ןוזמ",
            "7": "מ\"עב 'גייסרשטיינ ייפוי",
            "8": "12/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "29.233",
            "1": "",
            "2": "29.233",
            "3": "אל",
            "4": "",
            "5": "דנלוה",
            "6": "ןוזמ",
            "7": "BREHI",
            "8": "22/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "00.119",
            "1": "",
            "2": "00.119",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "ןוזמ",
            "7": "עבטו ןילבת",
            "8": "32/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "93.268",
            "1": "",
            "2": "93.268",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "קלד",
            "7": "ןורשה תלצבח ןולא רוד",
            "8": "32/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "31.248",
            "1": "",
            "2": "31.248",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "ןוזמ",
            "7": "הרדח  - יול ימר",
            "8": "42/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "90.129",
            "1": "",
            "2": "90.129",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "ןוזמ",
            "7": "הרדח ףוחה לומ םראפ-רפוס",
            "8": "52/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "60.99",
            "1": "",
            "2": "60.99",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "דוגיב",
            "7": "ףוח לומ הרדח",
            "8": "52/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "80.56",
            "1": "",
            "2": "80.56",
            "3": "אל",
            "4": "",
            "5": "עבק תארוה",
            "6": "תוריית",
            "7": "תישדוח תינובשח וגנפ",
            "8": "72/11/0202"
        },
        {
            "0": "91.142",
            "1": "20/12/02",
            "2": "",
            "3": "",
            "4": "",
            "5": "",
            "6": "",
            "7": "",
            "8": ""
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": ">> תוקסעה לע ףסונ טוריפל",
            "3": "",
            "4": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "",
            "3": "",
            "4": "סיטרכל יארשא תויביר"
        },
        {
            "0": "דע",
            "1": "ךיראתמ",
            "2": "תיביר",
            "3": "רועיש",
            "4": "תוליעפ גוס"
        },
        {
            "0": "ךיראת",
            "1": "",
            "2": "תיתנש",
            "3": "תיביר",
            "4": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "תמאותמ",
            "3": "תילנימונ",
            "4": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "01/40/02",
            "2": "11.12",
            "3": "60.11",
            "4": "03+"
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "",
            "3": "00.10",
            "4": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "01/40/02",
            "2": "35.13",
            "3": "60.12",
            "4": "טידרק"
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": "",
            "3": "00.11",
            "4": ""
        },
        {
            "0": "",
            "1": "",
            "2": ".קסעה יתבב תוקסעל תסחיתמ תיבירה - טידרק*",
            "3": "",
            "4": ""
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: I haven't well understood. Are you saying that all the text is flipped, while only hebrew text should be flipped?

Comment: All text is flipped, while none should be flipped.

Comment: Normally hebrew should be flipped because it is rtl, in this example hebrew is reversed (ltr) but also english and number (rtl), so that a fix is to flip all text

Comment: As a bypass, I search all word and check if they start with an 'end letter' which is a characteristic special to hebrew, if I find such word, I flip all text